# Print title on each page c#

Tags: c#, printing

I have this list with 5 indices and I want to print the title on a new page, what do I write so it prints it on the next page?

```
list<> // 5 indices

void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

    int startX = 10;
    int startY = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        graphic.DrawString(list[i].Title, new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain an instance variable which points to the current index of the item in the list to display , and increment it every time a page is printed.

```
int currIndex = 0;

void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;

    float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();

    int startX = 10;
    int startY = 10;

    graphic.DrawString(list[currIndex++].Title, new Font("Courier New", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY);
    if(currIndex == list.Count)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        currIndex = 0;
    } 
    else 
    {
        e.HasMorePages = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The printDocument object calls that same PrintPage() method for every page. If you want different content to appear on different pages, you need code that lives outside of that method to store the current state, and code within the method to check that state and resume/continue printing based on the state you stored outside of the method.

If you have instructions in the PrintPage() to print the title, then the title will be printed. End of story.